# Running same Python 2.7 script - slightly modified - simultaneously

Tags: python, bash, pyc

Will this work as intended- running `run.py` as the script was prior to running it - or will the changes made prior to the `New_York` run impact the run of `Chicago`?

```
$ python run.py CHICAGO 1
```

[modify `run.py` and `imported files` slightly]

```
$ python run.py NEW_YORK 0
```

Comment: Could you explain this more clearly? Are you changing the file?

Comment: It depends on what `run.py` does.  For example, if `run.py` alters something that it later reads, or deletes a resource, then it could affect the second run.  If they are running at the same time, and there are fixed filenames involved, then both might attempt to write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Interesting question! I'm pretty sure it will work as you intend, since a long-running program will be compiled and loaded into memory before you save the edited version to disk. But I don't have proof, hence this is not an answer. If it were me, though, I'd add an argument to the script so that you can get both kinds of desired behavior (or more than two) without editing the file between executions.